# Angular 2 interface for service

Tags: angular, typescript, service, interface

I want to develop a search component.
Here is the following use case:

1. This component calls a service with search's terms parameters.
2. The service call the api endpoint and returns the resulting objects as a
   collection.
3. The component display the results in the template.

I want to write only one search component able to call different service depending on the case.
Imagine I have two service:

1. SearchInMaleEmployeeService
2. SearchInFemaleEmployeeService

Both of these services implements a search function returning a list of employee.
I would like to tell my component which service depending on the case.
In C#, we can use interface to tell the component constructor which service to use.

How can I do that in Angular2?

Bonus question: How can I say to my component which template to use to render the search results depending of the type of object returned by the service?

Comment: Do you want to switch between services dynamicly or do you want to inject the proper service at component constructor?

Comment: I don't want to switch dynamicaly. I want to use the same searchComponent at different places with different service. But not dynamicaly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this via dependency injection.

As you said, create two different services implementing same `ISearchService` interface.

When using `SearchComponent`, provide appropriate service class from module to `ServiceComponent`.

Your `SearchComponent` would look like

```
  constructor(private searchService: ISearchService) {}
```

And when using `SearchComponent` at different places provide service instance:

```
providers: [
  { provide: ISearchService, useValue: SearchInMaleEmployeeService}
]
```

or

```
providers: [
  { provide: ISearchService, useValue: SearchInFemaleEmployeeService}
]
```

More information about Angular2 dependency injection [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html).

**Update:**

As pointed out by Ben

Provide statement needs to be coded as

```
provide('ISearchService', {useClass: SearchInMaleEmployeeService})
```

And to inject the class to component:

```
constructor(@Inject('ISearchService') private searchService:ISearchService) {}
```

Comment: Where do I have to write code to provide the service instance?

Comment: I try to add the code to the app.component, but I have an error: `@Component({ selector: 'app-root', templateUrl: 'app.component.html', providers: [ { provide: ISearchService, useValue: SearchInMaleEmployeeService}, ] })`. Error:  Cannot find name 'ISearchService'. But the import works without error: `import { ISearchService } from './_services/searchservice/interface/isearchservice.interface';`

Comment: It's because interface are not injectable. I have to use the provide name as a string. But now when I run the program I have an error: `Can't resolve all parameters for SearchComponent: (AuthService, NgZone, ?).` that mean Angular 2 don't know how to resolve the interface.

Comment: You need to write that code to module declaration, not component. Check out the link at end of the answer. Plenty of declaration examples in there.

Comment: I solved my problem with this code: `provide('ISearchService', {useClass: SearchInMaleEmployeeService})` in the component hosting the searchComponent and this code: `constructor(@Inject('ISearchService') private searchService:ISearchService) {}` in the searchComponent constructor. Can you update you post (as I can accept it as answer)?

Comment: I have been trying to get a plunktr working for you. Glad you get it working. Updated my answer with your updated info.

Comment: I just figured out that I have another problem, when I try to run my search method in my component: `searchService.search(...)` I got an error: `EXCEPTION: Error in ./SearchComponent class SearchComponent - inline template:0:127 caused by:  this.searchService.search is not a function`. But in VSCode, the search function is known.

Comment: Angular won't want a typescript interface, I used an abstract class- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#why-minimallogger-is-a-class-and-not-a-typescript-interface

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it like [Sefa Ümit Oray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312692/sefa-%C3%9Cmit-oray) answered above. But as I understand, you are trying to filter two type of object in list and you want to use both. So why you don't write a service that has two difference search methods. Or you can write a method that do search in both types of object.

As you ask, you can use `instance of` to check the type of object. Then, use `Pipe` combine with `ngIf` to do render what you want.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html