# Angular 6 service with interface

Tags: angular, typescript, service, dependency-injection, angular6

I am building an application with Angular (`6.0.7`) and I am trying to create a service with the new:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

But how can I type an injection with an Interface?

---

**The problem**

I have 2 services, **Authentication.service** and **SessionStorage.service**. I want to inject the sessionstorage into the authentication service. That can be done via:

```
constructor(private sessionStorage: SessionStorage) {
}
```

No problem there. But for Object Orientated purposes I want to have an `interface` above this service (so that I can implement both localstorage service as sessionstorage service). Thus it is only logical that I want to type the injected class with the interface, but this cannot be done the same way [Angular 5 and lower does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068456/angular-2-interface-for-service).

So how can I type the injection into this global service with my interface?

---

**I've tried**

The Angular service typings describe an `InjectableProvider`, but this does not match any of the parameters of the siblings of `InjectableProvider`, so this gives a compiler (and tslint) error.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}, {provide: IStorageService, useClass: SessionStorage})
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of that. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Dependency injection like it should be, the class uses an interface and doesn't care about the implementation of the code. Sure Angular works a bit differend with the need to type the injection with 'useValue' everywhere, but it serves the same purpose.

Comment: And why don't you use the interface with `export class MyService implements MyInterface {...}` ?

Comment: And BTW, `useValue` requires a value (an actual instance of a class), and `useClass` allows you to use classes. So try with `useClass`, and maybe `useInterface` (but this one I'm not sure)

Comment: @trichetriche, unfortunately the `useClass` does not work either, since it does not match the parameter of the InjectableProvider (updated answer). About 'why don't you use (..) implements (..)', I don't want to do that because that way I still have to set the exact type in the constructor and I want to avoid that if possible

Comment: And what about using a factory with `useFactory` ? this would cope with the signature. And you don't have to set the exact type in the constructor, you can create a `SotrageInterface` for instance, which is not the exact type and would still allow you to use `implements`

Comment: I think it's a duplication of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495384/1435187 (which have a solution)

Comment: @FabiF, I agree it looks a lot like that question, but the big difference is that he is using an abstract class on which the can define the 'use class', where I am using an interface to define it's type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done with `InjectionToken`, which is a replacement for the obsolete `OpaqueToken`

```
export const AuthenticationProvider = new InjectionToken(
  "AuthenticationProvider",
  { providedIn: "root", factory: () => new CognitoAuthenticationProvider() }
);

...

@Injectable()
export class CognitoAuthenticationProvider implements IAuthenticationProvider {

...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(AuthenticationProvider)
    private authenticationProvider: IAuthenticationProvider,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}
```

Comment: I think this is the best option, unfortunately it needs yet an other variable and the `provideIn` needs to be defined on the token, where I would expect it to be defined on the service.

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy the `providedIn` is new in ng 6 and is recommended for some tree-shaking optimisation purpose. you can still register providers in the modules themselves.

Comment: I agree with you on that (I really like the new `providedIn` option), but what I ment was that you can no longer decalre this on the service itself. It has to be declared on the injection token, otherwise it will not be available in the whole application.

Comment: what if we would like to inject something into 'CognitoAuthenticationProvider' constructor?

Comment: I pay attention on the interface `IAuthenticationProvider` name. Angular style guide says: [Consider naming an interface without an I prefix.](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03)

Comment: @tsiro I had the same question. Angular docs state the following about that: `When creating an InjectionToken, you can optionally specify a factory function which returns (possibly by creating) a default value of the parameterized type T. This sets up the InjectionToken using this factory as a provider as if it was defined explicitly in the application's root injector. If the factory function, which takes zero arguments, needs to inject dependencies, it can do so using the inject function.` They provide an [example](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#description).

Comment: @tsiro Also keep in mind the `factory` parameter is optional, and only provides a default for the injection token. You might be in a case where you don't have a default to provide, in which case you shouldn't use the `factory` parameter at all. This would let angular fail with an error if you hadn't configured the injector to have any services to inject with that token elsewhere. You can setup the provider when adding your service to a module to use `providers: [{ provide: YOUR_TOKEN, useClass: YourConcreteClass }]`

Answer (score 8):

I used something like the following to solve this

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
  { provide: AlmostInterface, useClass: environment.concrete }
  ...
]
```

**AlmostInterface.ts**

```
export abstract class AlmostInterface {
   abstract myMethod();
}
```

**MyConcrete.ts**

```
export class MyConcrete implements AlmostInterface {
   myMethod() { ... }; // implementation
}

export class MyConcreteAlternative implements AlmostInterface {
   myMethod() { ... }; // implementation
}
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  concrete: MyConcreteAlternative
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  concrete: MyConcrete
};
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is that this uses the old Angular 5 syntax for declaring a service. I am asking for a solution with the new Angular 6 syntax, since this (`provideIn: 'root'`) is not declared via the module, but is only injected in the components that use it (better for tree shaking).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't use typescript interfaces for dependency injection as **typescript interfaces don't exist** at runtime (only for typesafety at compile time).

I would suggest using an **abstract class** for it.

EDIT:
It seems you can use `useClass` in the **first** parameter of @Injectable, not as a second like your example. Combining that with @k0zakinio's answer results in:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
  useClass: environment.concrete,
  deps: []
})
export abstract class SessionStorage { }
```

It also seems you need to declare your dependencies via `deps` or `inject`, checkout this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23592). I hope this time my answer is of more help.

Comment: Well, Angular (and Typescript) does provide a way for dependency injection, see @k0zakinio's answer. So it is possible. But I want to know if it's also possible for the Angular 6 way of services.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like -

```
[{ provide: InterfaceName, useClass: ClassName}]
```

Comment: This does not match the params defined by the `InjectableProvider`, so unfortunately this does not work