# Angular Interface for Service in HTML Selector

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

How do I provide Dependency Injection through a HTML Selector? Following answer is through typescript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068594/14432516

```
providers: [
  { provide: ISearchService, useValue: SearchInFemaleEmployeeService}
]
```

I want to do something similar in html from Parent, and use Male/Female Employee Search Service. Parent component has this html.

```
<app-search-component>
</app-search-component>
```

I read it can be done through Module? However, this Module calls Search Component many times in html, and may require Male Or FemaleEmployee Search Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, dependency injection is a static processus, if you want to keep things static, you can have two components `<app-search-female-component>` and `<app-search-male-component>`, declared like this

```
// <app-search-female-component>
constructor(
    private searchService:SearchInFemaleEmployeeService
) {}

// <app-search-male-component>
constructor(
    private searchService:SearchInMaleEmployeeService
) {}
```

---

Or declare one search component with a parameter giving the type of service you want to use

```
// <app-search-component type="male">
@Input()
public type: string;
constructor(
    private maleSearchService:SearchInFemaleEmployeeService,
    private femaleSearchService:SearchInMaleEmployeeService,
) {}
```

---

There are plenty of ways to achieve what you want. I would prefer the second one because we locate the choice of the service inside the component. I mean at some point you will have to tell programmatically and dynamically what search type you want to choose and it is good if it is isolated somewhere. The less switches the better :)

---

**Edit**: I understand that you will have 20-30 services here, so you don't want to inject the 20-30 services in your search component.
You can then create a service `SelectorService` used to select the search service to be used. **Doing so, the injection of the 20-30 services is done only once**, in the `SelectorService` and your component only inject one service.

```
// SelectorService
constructor(
    private maleSearchService:SearchInFemaleEmployeeService,
    private femaleSearchService:SearchInMaleEmployeeService,
    ...
) {}

selectSearchService(type: string): ISearchService {
    switch (type) {
    ....
    }
}

// <app-search-component type="male">
@Input()
public type: string;
constructor(
    private selector:SelectorService,
) {}
```

Comment: well not sure if this will work, because I may have 20-30 types in the future, I only provided a simple example

Comment: okay ! And the 20-30 will coexist in your parent ? I'm wondering why going to injection model. Why not having one service generating dynamically the search endpoint based on parameters ?

Comment: they will probably be utilized in many different components as needed for web store, etc

Comment: I tried to edit my answer. Does that fit better your need ?